# Exploratory analysis with logistic regression - Do I need to split into training and test sets?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, training-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset that I am just exploring at the moment. One thing I am interested in is whether some variables classify a particular outcome measure. I want to use logistic regression just to see how well the it does. In this situation is it okay to just use the entire dataset to training and then predict on (see code below) or even in this exploratory phase should I be splitting into training and test sets?

```
    model_glm = glm(outcome ~ var1 + var2, data = DataSet, family = "binomial")
    prob = predict(model_glm, newdata = DataSet, type = "response")
    roc = roc(DataSet$outcome ~ prob, plot = TRUE, print.auc = TRUE)
    as.numeric(roc$auc)
    coords(roc, "best")
```

I tried splitting the dataset into training and test sets as well as the above code. My results were similar.

Comment: In the exploratory phase, you don't need to split your dataset. You will explore the split dataset (train and test) to see if the model has bias or variance. Or if you would like to see the distribution of each dataset.

Comment: Thanks. How would you suggest assessing bias and variance of the model?

Comment: There is a great post on the data science StackExchange site. The [What are Bias and Variance?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80157/what-are-bias-and-variance-in-machine-learning) answer tells how to handle it. I would also recommend Andrew Ng's Machine Learning Specialization course in Coursera.